# How can I change the index column using Material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Im using [Material-table](https://material-table.com/) and I need to alter column index to put at the end of table because by default this column (actions) it is in the beginning.

Below the table code:

```
 <MaterialTable
    title=""
    icons={tableIcons}
    localization={{
      body: {
        editRow: {
          saveTooltip: "Salvar",
          cancelTooltip: "Cancelar",
          deleteText: "Tem certeza que deseja deletar este registro?"
        },
        addTooltip: "Adicionar",
        deleteTooltip: "Deletar",
        editTooltip: "Editar"
      },
      header: {
        actions: "Ações"
      }
    }}
    columns={state.columns}
    data={state.data}
    editable={{
      onRowAdd: newData => createInstructor(newData),
      onRowUpdate: async (newData, oldData) =>
        updateInstructor(newData, oldData),
      onRowDelete: oldData => deleteInstructor(oldData)
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dedicated option [actionsColumnIndex](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props):

> **actionsColumnIndex** *number* *0* - Order of actions column

In order to make your actions column the last, assign a value of `-1` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `options` with property `actionsColumnIndex`. The default value is 0. It means that it always locate at first columns.

If you want to move it to last column. Just simply do:

```
<MaterialTable
   options={{
      actionsColumnIndex: -1
   }}
/>
```